# three.js updating camera matrix world

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, webgl, perspectivecamera

I'm trying to make the camera project a cube into an image of a cube. I calculate the camera's internal and external parameters. I update the camera internal matrix by manually changing the projectionmatrix. the code is:

```
camera.projectionMatrix.elements[i]= value;
```

but for some reeason when i want to update its external parameters, by updating either camera.matrixWorld or camera.matrixWorldInverse nothing happens. i use this code:

```
 camera.matrixWorldInverse.elements[i]= value;
 camera.matrixWorld.elements[i]= value;
```

if i update both still nothing happens. what am I doing wrong? how can I update the camera's external parameters?

Answer (score 3):

Your values may be getting overwritten. Try this:

```
camera.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
```

Comment: you are right they are getting overwritten. SO i did what you did and now I have the following two problems:

1. nothing gets loaded onto the page. there is no more projection.
2. the matrix go back to the identity matrix in the render

Comment: Did you have any chance to look over it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `scene.updateMatrixWorld()` after changing the world matrix.